Lazarus, ошибка при делении чисел
Есть функция:
function DiscontValue(MoneyValue: real; CurrentTime: integer;
         Tau: integer; ProcentRate: double; h: double = 1): real;
begin
   Result := MoneyValue / (1 + ProcentRate * ((CurrentTime - Tau)/h));
   writeln(floattostr(Result));
end;

При ее вызове:
s1 := DiscontValue(1000, 3, 0, 0.25);

в строке
writeln(floattostr(Result));

выходит ошибка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно приводить типы при делении? Или я что-то делаю не так?

Без печати работает? Какое значение получается? Проект консольный?

@MBo Без печати выдает число не то, которое нужно (5.7142857142857144E+002, а нужно 547,43). И при сложении с другими числами дает так же не тот результат. Знаменатель в формуле дает правильный результат, я проверял. Проект консольный.

В Delphi получается то же самое значение 571.428571428571 (оно же 5.71428571428571E+0002), и это верное значение (1000/1.75), вылета нет. И избавьтесь от real, замените на double

Если это деньги, то лучше все же не числа с плавающей точкой, а с фиксированной (https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Currency), чтобы не было потом чудных проблем

Я поменял тип Real и Double на Currency и все заработало.

Однако значение всё-таки  571.428, так?

@MBo да, оно такое и должно быть.
